Diffbot/robot not responding to teleop_keyboard_twist command in rviz2
My current setup: Ubuntu 22.0 running ROS Humble Hawksbill.
Issue at hand:-
I'm using the teleop_twist_keyboard package to control a robot in RViz with my keyboard. Here's the command I'm running:
ros2 run teleop_twist_keyboard teleop_twist_keyboard --ros-args -r cmd_vel:=/diffbot_base_controller/cmd_vel
I noticed that the robot does not respond to the keyboard inputs when I press the letters u , i , o ; j , k , l ; m , < , > .
Any help or direction as to whats causing this issue and possible solutions are highly appreciated.
(Here is the tutorial I followed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J02jEKawE5U&list=PLunhqkrRNRhYAffV8JDiFOatQXuU-NnxT&index=22 . You can start watching from 4:10 onwards for relevant info, The issue I ran into is at 6:00).
What i have debugged so far
Upon running the command ros2 topic echo /diffbot_base_controller/cmd_vel the result I get is in the form of:
linear:
  x: 0.7
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular:
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 1.0

However, when I tried giving an input to the bot directly via terminal using
ros2 topic pub --rate 30 /diffbot_base_controller/cmd_vel geometry_msgs/msg/TwistStamped "
    twist:
      linear:
        x: 0.7
        y: 0.0
        z: 0.0
      angular:
        x: 0.0
        y: 0.0
        z: 1.0"

I was able to successfully move the bot in a circular pattern.
This leads me to believe that the robot expects messages in the form of "TwistStamped" with the twist header also being a part of the msg.
Does anyone know of a ready-made tool or package in ROS2 that can transform Twist messages to TwistStamped messages with the necessary header? Or is there an alternative approach to solving this issue without writing a custom node?
Thanks in advance for your help!

The primary issue is that teleop sends commands in the following message format (twist message)
 linear:
    x: 0.7
    y: 0.0
    z: 0.0
  angular:
    x: 0.0
    y: 0.0
    z: 1.0

where as rviz expects the messages to be of the format (twist stamped message)
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1719912152
    nanosec: 27579207
  frame_id: base_link
twist:
  linear:
    x: 0.0
    y: 0.0
    z: 0.0
  angular:
    x: 0.0
    y: 0.0
    z: 0.0

It works fine even without the header but the twist attribute is essential for rviz to recognize the data.
I found a package on GitHub that does exactly whats needed and has good Read-me as well (written by Josh Newman).
You can install it using the command sudo apt install ros-$ROS_DISTRO-twist-stamper where $ROS_DISTRO is a macro and downloads the version specific to your ROS version.
Leaving this answer here so it's useful to anyone that has the same issue in the future.
Cheers!
